# What is wrong with this HTML?! Makes more padding each print page

Tags: html, css

Here's my site:

http://shoutkey.com/embrace

Using Chrome, go to Print and then choose No margins.

Now check the top padding and how everything is nice on Page 1.

Now go to page 25. Check the top padding, like there is none? I dont understand, why it slowly makes less and less padding at the top, and then increases again after like page 26, then it gets more and more top padding.

How can i fix this? This is driving me crazy, 3+ hours trying to figure out

Comment: You need to post the code here, people don't wanna be going onto specific pages of other websites etc.

Comment: print takes the empty space also while printing. that is why you are getting white space in few pages

Comment: @SowmyaShivaram Where do I have empty spaces? All elements have the exact same content

Comment: @Karem padding-bottom:60px for .box

Comment: @SowmyaShivaram Ok I have removed this and increased height instead, so the page still looks correct 2x4 . But still already at page 7 now the top padding is gone ?

Comment: @SowmyaShivaram Im adding style="padding-top: 14mm;" to create a top padding, after 8 listed items (after 1 page)

Comment: make the effort to create a fiddle/equivalent if you want us to make the effort to help you.

Comment: @leMoisela Here http://jsfiddle.net/ke3cs/ , but you need to have the result on a separate page to test and see what i mean about Printing and the weird top padding change ?

Comment: @SowmyaShivaram I found out that padding and height make it work but then the top padding gets uncontrolled and changes itself on each pages, but if i use margin nothing changes and page 2,3,4 etc just dont have any top padding

Answer (score 0):

Use page break (`page-break-before: always`) to break the page while printing.

Here is the link which explains that http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks